# How to use mrec in windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, anaconda

I am learning how to use `mrec`. `mrec` is a Python package developed by Mendeley to support recommender systems development and evaluation.

[mrec recommender systems library](http://mendeley.github.io/mrec/)

However, it looks that mrec may be just runned in Linux. (both installation is OK, BUT just run in Linux, not windows.)

After installed, I try to use the example [Getting started with mrec](http://mendeley.github.io/mrec/quickstart.html) in Windows CMD.

But I get this error:

```
D:\Anaconda2\Scripts>python mrec_prepare-script.py --dataset ml-100k/u.data --outdir splits --rating_thresh 4 --test_size 0.5 --binarize
[****************] INFO: sorting input data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mrec_prepare-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mrec==0.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'mrec_prepare')()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mrec\examples\prepare.py", line 76, in main
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 536, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2]
```

What's the problem?

Comment: which part of the tutorial is giving you the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem and solved by making sure I am in the right directory. If you are running this command where `ml-data` is stored, you're good to use the above command:

```
python mrec_prepare-script.py --dataset ml-100k/u.data --outdir splits --rating_thresh 4 --test_size 0.5 --binarize
```

So, make sure you're in the right **directory**

Comment: Well, I am sorry to tell you that it gets the same error. I have try serial representations of directory, these were the command I have tried:    (1) F:\PythonProjects\Mrec>python mrec_prepare-script.py --dataset F:/PythonProjects/Mrec/ml-100k/u.data --outdir F:/PythonProjects/Mrec/splits/ --rating_thresh 4 --test_size 0.5 --binarize    (2) F:\PythonProjects\Mrec>mrec_prepare --dataset F:/PythonProjects/Mrec/ml-100k/u.data --outdir F:/PythonProjects/Mrec/splits/ --rating_thresh 4 --test_size 0.5 --binarize